# Receiving an object via ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, serialization, io, nullpointerexception, objectinputstream

I'm writing a server-client application with Java, on Android and Windows. I want to send the user's information (Username and password) to the server for verification. client sends the object containing the information, but the server doesn't receive it!
here is the Object class:

```
package Model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class StringObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String Username=null;
private String Password=null;

public void setPassword(String Password){
    this.Password=Password;
}
public void setUsername(String Username){
    this.Username=Username;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return Password;
}
public String getUsername(){
    return Username;
}
}
```

The client code:

```
private void Login(){
    try {
ObjectOutputStream OutObj=new  ObjectOutputStream(newBufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()));
                OutObj.writeObject(UserPass);
                OutObj.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Application: ",e.toString());}
```

(I've set the Object variable's before this lines)

and the server code:

```
  ObjectInputStream inObj = new ObjectInputStream(new         BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()));
        UserPass=(StringObject) inObj.readObject();
        System.out.println("UserName: " + UserPass.getUsername());
        System.out.println("Password: " + UserPass.getPassword());
```

the client program (android) crashes with error: thread exiting with uncaught Exception.
(the socket and I/O code lines are in a seperated thread)

```
07-15 12:43:59.626: W/dalvikvm(1306): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-89
07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.Login(ConnectionThread.java:90)
07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.ProcessMessage(ConnectionThread.java:70)
07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:47)
```

But when I replace the `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` with `BufferedWriter`/`bufferedReader` it works fine! can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Please, paste the crash dump and the error code so we can tell you where and perhaps, why it happens.

Comment: Which is line 90 in your Login method?

Comment: Side note: Java's naming conventions follow the [lowerCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms) notation.

Comment: Line 90 is: if(in.readLine().equals("Valid")){   ... but the server doesn't send "Valid" message, cause it doesn't recieve the object!

Comment: Ah, so you're reading and writing objects, _and_ other data to the stream. Do you disconnect the ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream and connect a different io/stream to the OutputSteram (or just use a new BufferedStream)? If you do, that's likely your problem, that the BufferedStream is consuming more data than the object input stream is reading, so the next stream you connect isn't seeing any data. Thus in.readLine() returns null, and your crash.

Comment: yes, this is the problem. so I'll use one inputStream. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create new object streams per transaction. Use the same streams for the life of the socket, at both ends. The object streams read and write headers, so creating multiple instances per socket just gets out of sync with the other end.

Comment: I need to send a message to server via BufferedWriter and send an object via ObjectOutpuStream. in both cases I use connection.getOutputStream() . what should I do?

Comment: The problem is not the writing. The problem is reading. You can use a BufferedInputStream/BufferedReader, but if you disconnect that and attach a second reader to the same stream, the first bufferedreader may have read more bytes than your wrapper actually consumed. So, for example, having ObjectInputStream(BufferedInputStream(InputSteam)).readObject() may read more bytes than just those for the object into the Buffered stream... (like your "valid" text), so if you stop reading there and use a different reader attached to the input stream, the data may no longer be in there.

Comment: very nice! thanks. so... what should I do? instead of BufferedReader.readLine() and then ObjectInputStream.readObject() what should I use?

Comment: There are many choices, e.g. readUTF()/writeUTF(), but why not send *everything* as an object?

Comment: yes! sending everything as an object will work! I'm trying it. thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

```
   07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): java.lang.NullPointerException
   07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.Login(ConnectionThread.java:90)
   07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.ProcessMessage(ConnectionThread.java:70)
   07-15 12:43:59.626: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.shayan.filesharing.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:47)
```

Can you show the fine `ConnectionThread.java` on `line 90` ? You're getting a nullpointer there which may not have anything to do with your networking, but a bad / non-initialized reference.

Comment: you mean the line 90? yes :      if(in.readLine().equals("Valid")){     Log.d("Application: ","Valid"); }   probably it's the in.readline() that is null, but in (Input Stream) is already initializad!

Comment: You must check the result of readLine() for null before you do anything else with it.